# Get to know later on the max memory size that was allocated by new

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

How do we retrieve and/or get to know later on the max size of memory that was allocated by new
e.g.

```
 int *p = new int[70]
```

Comment: That's an implementation detail. You cannot know, nor should you care.

Comment: All you need to know is that you were allocated what you asked for. Of course there are times where it can fail the allocation, but very unlikely. Why would you need to know how much it actually allocated and what not, you wouldn't be able to access it anyways

Comment: Remember that the request is a *minimum* amount of memory.  If you ask for 23 bytes, the OS may round up to 24 bytes (alignment) or may tack on some overhead (such as a link to the next allocated block).  Search the internet for "c++ memory management" and "memory pools".

Comment: In C++ we should not use ````new````

Comment: @ArminMontigny, in C++ we SHOULD use new.... what language are you talking about...

Comment: @OmidCompSCI. No, definitely not. We should not use raw pointers for owned memory in C++. We should use ````std::unique_ptr```` and ````std::make_unique````. Also, avoid C-Style arrays with new[]. Use dynamic containers. If you drive a car with a wireless break system, would you like to have raw pointers, new and other dangerous stuff in it? You should avoid pointers and ````new```` wherever you can. Why, for whatever reason, would you use ````new```` like in the question above? Use a ````std::vector```` or ````std::array````. But not ````new````

Comment: @ArminMontigny, not all C++ supports the new std::ptr types, and there are systems out there that are developed using older C++ versions, which we use new.